# Geowebcache is not using bounding box parameter when seeding

Tags: tiles, geowebcache

I have an issue where when I am seeding tiles for a layer with Geowebcache, the tiles are seeded to the full extent of the layer despite my use of the bounding box parameter. My goal, of course, is to constrain where the tiles are generated to a specific extent.

I have seen the bounding box parameter specified in two ways (I am using JSON format for both):

1. This page (https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/geowebcache/rest/seed.html) suggests using following format:

`'bounds':{'coords':{ 'double':['-124.0','22.0','66.0','72.0']}}`

2. The web interface (ie. https://server.org/geoserver/gwc/rest/seed/<layer_name>) seems to send the bounding box parameter is a different format:

```
         "minX": -1100000,
         "minY": 5000000,
         "maxX": -9500000,
         "maxY": 6600000,
```

Neither of these have worked for me.

Could someone please advise me on how to specify the bounding box when seeding tiles?

**EDIT**
I should clarify that the tiles are generated fine. **But** they are generated *outside* of the bounding box parameter I specify. Indeed, they seem to obey the default extent (or bounding box) of the layer itself.

**So, how can I constrain the tile generation to a specific extent?**

Comment: Please look in the log files and add any relevant error messages to your question using the [edit] button

Comment: @IanTurton, I didn't think to look in the logs because the tiles actually do generate (just beyond where I want them to). But I will check and see; maybe there is something there to indicate why it is not using the bounding box parameter I specify.

Comment: How did you check where you have pre-seeded tiles and where not?

Comment: @user30184, good question. I seeded the cache for a layer that has an extent larger than my preferred bounding box. When I use the _Tile Layer Preview_ within Geoserver web interface the layer displays at its full extent. I double check that it was hitting tiles, by examining the [geowebcache response headers](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/geowebcache/responseheaders.html#http-response-headers)

Answer (score 1):

The example from the GeoServer documentation begins to seed for me. I made the default binary zip installation of GeoServer for the test and I only changed the seed request type into 'seed' and made the bounds smaller.

```
curl -v -u admin:geoserver -XPOST -H "Content-type: application/json" -d "{'seedRequest':{'name':'topp:states','bounds':{'coords':{ 'double':['-124.0','22.0','-120','23.0']}},'srs':{'number':4326},'zoomStart':1,'zoomStop':12,'format':'image\/png','type':'seed','threadCount':4}}}"  "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/rest/seed/topp:states.json"
```

Here the same command as plain text for clarity.

> curl -v -u admin:geoserver -XPOST -H "Content-type: application/json"
> -d "{'seedRequest':{'name':'topp:states','bounds':{'coords':{ 'double':['-124.0','22.0','-120','23.0']}},'srs':{'number':4326},'zoomStart':1,'zoomStop':12,'format':'image/png','type':'seed','threadCount':4}}}"
> "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/rest/seed/topp:states.json"

Comment: are the resulting tiles limited to the bounding box you specified? They weren't in my case.

Comment: That BBOX was covering the whole site. This seeded a small area of topp:states just fine `curl -v -u admin:geoserver -XPOST -H "Content-type: application/json" -d "{'seedRequest':{'name':'topp:states','bounds':{'coords':{ 'double':['-124.0','22.0','-120','23.0']}},'srs':{'number':4326},'zoomStart':1,'zoomStop':12,'format':'image\/png','type':'seed','threadCount':4}}}"  "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/rest/seed/topp:states.json"`